# Does unused function add execution time in PHP in small scale?

Tags: performance, php-7

Let's say I have a file with 40 functions, and 3/4 are rarely used. Is it a better idea to separate them into several files and load only on demand or 30, 100  extra functions is not a big deal? Taking into consideration that APCu in on.

Comment: It's better for maintainability and understandability of your codebase to organise your code sensibly and clearly. But performance-wise, this question smacks a bit of trying to prematurely optimise to me. Are you experiencing any performance problems? If not: I'd not worry about it. Focus on the human side of your code's performance rather than the machine side of it.

Comment: APCu does not affect speed for loading code, that's OPcache's job.